# clone mercurial repository to remote machine

Tags: linux, mercurial

is there any way to clone my mercurial repository to a separate machine ? (might be a silly question, but i'm pretty new to mercurial )

i want to clone the whole repository from a CentOS machine to an Ubuntu machine for some testing and i don't want to mess anything up on my working machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SSH access, can go

```
tar c '/path/to/your/repository' | ssh username@somemachine 'tar x'
```

That will get the repository and the current working directory over there.

Comment: Doesn't tar work by default with tapes?  If you're feeding it from stdin, you'll probably need a `-f -` at the end of that tar invocation.

Comment: The `f` flag means "_read from file_", at least in [GNU tar.](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/file-tutorial.html#SEC14)

Answer (score 0):

Of Course, Go to the the Ubuntu Machine, install Mercurial, and clone your repository in the CentOs Machine from the Ubuntu machine.

Now you have a clone repository from the CentOS in another Machine, make your changes in the Ubuntu Machine, if you agreed with the changes, then push the Changes to remote repository(CentOs Machine).